# App returns NOT FOUND when registering a user

Tags: android, mysql

During my app register process, server returns "Not found" when attempting to register a user to my mySQL database . Seems i'm unable to add data to my database.don't really know if the problem is coming from my code or my database.

I really need help or a clue on how to solve this problem cause I've been on it for days now. Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Give more details. What are you making the request on mobile?

Comment: I'm making the request from mobile

Comment: Sorry, wanted to ask how. Are you using retrofit, asyncTask, give us code in order to help.

Comment: @AdrianComan I'm using retrofit